# Merging text files in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

New at Excel macros so need some help. I have about 60+ text files in a single directory each with just one column of data. I am trying to get/write a macro that will import all the text files but also add a second column that contains the file name.

I have the 2 steps I am trying to do. First Sub gets me the list of file names, the second sub gets my the content of the txt files. So the end result I am looking for is a single sheet with the txt content in column A and the source file's name in column B. I am struggling to get the file name in. The files imports must fallow below each other.

```
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$

InitialFoldr$ = "C:\Desktop" '<<< Startup folder to begin searching from

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
    .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
        Do While xFname$ <> ""
            ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = Left(xFname$, InStrRev(xFname$, ".") - 1)
            xRow = xRow + 1
            xFname$ = Dir
            With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
               "TEXT;" & xFname$, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            End With

        Loop
    End If
End With

End Sub

Sub TextContent()

Dim myfiles
Dim i As Integer

myfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Text Files (*.txt),    *.txt", MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsEmpty(myfiles) Then
    For i = LBound(myfiles) To UBound(myfiles)
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" & myfiles(i), Destination:=Range("A" & Rows.Count).End  (xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
            .Name = "Sample"
            .FieldNames = False
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
End If

End Sub



Sub FileList()

Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$

InitialFoldr$ = "C:\Desktop" '<<< Startup folder to begin searching from

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
    .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
        Do While xFname$ <> ""
            ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = Left(xFname$, InStrRev(xFname$, ".") - 1)
            xRow = xRow + 1
            xFname$ = Dir
            With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
               "TEXT;" & xFname$, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            End With

        Loop
    End If
End With

End Sub

Sub TextContent()

Dim myfiles
Dim i As Integer

myfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Text Files (*.txt),   *.txt", MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsEmpty(myfiles) Then
    For i = LBound(myfiles) To UBound(myfiles)
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" & myfiles(i), Destination:=Range("A" & Rows.Count).End  (xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
            .Name = "Sample"
            .FieldNames = False
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If the second column only has one row of data (the filename) why not just name the Sheet the filename instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want.

```
Sub ImportTextFiles()
    Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For iRow = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Reset the text variable
        text = ""
        ' Compose the full path
        myFile = Range("A" & iRow).Value & "\" & Range("B" & iRow).Value
        ' Open the file
        Open myFile For Input As #1
        ' Loop through the lines of the file
        Do Until EOF(1)
            ' Read a line
            Line Input #1, textline
            ' Concatenate text
            text = text & " " & textline
        Loop
        ' Close the file
        Close #1
        ' Write text to cell
        Range("C" & iRow).Value = Mid(text, 2)
    Next iRow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Feel free to modify the script to suit your specific needs.  Keep in mind, you can do pretty much whatever you want to do...

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Sure.  Go ahead and up-vote my post if it helped you.